# Brand new to PHP: Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to setup my website (selling my album for dogecoin) and I just got the source.

Im getting this error:

```
Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in /home/ethjck/public_html/includes/classes/Purchase.php on line 59
```

The line in question is

```
$query_new_tx_insert->bindValue(':dogecoin_address', $dogecoin_address, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

and is part of

```
$query_new_tx_insert = $database->getDBConnection()->prepare('INSERT INTO transactions (txid, name, email, address, ip_address, datetime) VALUES(:txid, :user_name, :user_email, :dogecoin_address, :user_ip, now())');
    $query_new_tx_insert->bindValue(':txid', $txid, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query_new_tx_insert->bindValue(':user_name', $user_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query_new_tx_insert->bindValue(':user_email', $user_email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query_new_tx_insert->bindValue(':dogecoin_address', $dogecoin_address, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query_new_tx_insert->bindValue(':user_ip', $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query_new_tx_insert->execute();
```

Can I get help?

Comment: may be $dogecoin_address is an stdClass object var_dump($dogecoin_address) to check it..!

Comment: Where did you get the software? Your best source is the author.